# Can't load mnist dataset on google cloud ml

Tags: tensorflow, mnist, google-cloud-ml

I want to run simple deep learning model for MNIST on google cloud ml. I try to download and unpack it via tensroflow's utility method tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist. Unfortunately, when I use it in the cloud, it's not visible to my code. I have exception like this: No such file or directory: 'gs://bucket/path/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz When I browse the bucket, the file is there, but tensorflow doesn't see it.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, TensorFlow's file system abstraction does not properly support Python's gzip library. As a result, mnist.read_data_sets only supports a `train_dir` on the local filesystem, i.e., you cannot use GCS with the utility functions.

The workaround is to create a temporary directory on the local filesystem and use that instead.

It seems to me that this is the default in the examples, e.g., [`mnist_softmax.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py#L76) has a flag, `--data-dir`, that by default points to '/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data'. To verify, I copied the contents of [`mnist_softmax.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) into a new Python script which successfully ran on Cloud Machine Learning Engine. Also worked for [`mnist_deep.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py)

However, if you're going to manually use [`read_data_sets`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L189) (via `tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py`), be sure to pass a local directory as the first argument.

Comment: But how can I use temporary directory on the local file system? Where is it located?

Comment: When you submit a job to the cloud you have full access to the filesystem of the worker. The scripts above hard-code `/tmp`. That works fine. You can also use Python's `tempfile.mkdtemp`.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov if you add a code snippet to your question I can probably help better.

Comment: Ok. Will try it. I solved the problem for now with manually written reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used the reader which was provided with the tensorflow, and it was able to work only with the local file system. In order to read mnist, you have to use tensorflow.python.lib.io package.